# how to work embedded expressions ${...} in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-shim

How to work **embedded expressions e.g. ${...}** work. when I work in javascript it work perfect. but not in HTML. so My question is ES6 check all String (literal or object) in runtime and string interpolation.

ex:

```
var i = "${4 + 2}";
var j = new String(`${4 + 1}`);
console.log(i);  //result 6
console.log(j);  //result 5
```

but in HTML

```
<body>
    Addition = ${5+6}  //show Addition = ${5+6}
</body>
```

Comment: ES6 won't look up your HTML, just your JS file, what you just have done in html is printing a string

Comment: Uh? Lets take a step back. If I do `1 + 3` in JavaScript, I perform an addition operation and get the result `4`. If I write `1 + 3` in HTML, I literally see `1 + 3` on the page. HTML is not a programming language and it has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is completely separate from javascript, if you need dynamic data updates of your HTMl, you can use javascript to update the content of the HTML tag, or use libraries such as [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), or if you want something more complex, [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) to update the HTML for you, based on the logic you describe.

Here is a [good introductory course on these topics on CodeCademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/html-javascript-css/0/1)